# Quotas with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, quota

```
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
12770 2385K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           quota: 2000000 bytes
0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

How can this be? I've set limit to 2M, but it's now 2.385M and still accepting

Since 2010-07-23 15:07:47 commit "report initial quota value instead of current value to userspace" it became uncertain what the current value of quota is and I relied on bytes counter (when I reset the quota the counter is reset too). Why it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just revert this commit and enjoy quotas.

(Hovewer, I see inconsistent measurements sometimes; but in general in more works than not).

Considering netfilter quotas unreliable (both usual and with reverted commit).